# MATLAB plot3 left handed coordinate system

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I would like to display some data in Matlab using `plot3`. This data makes the most sense in the left handed coordinate system.

[image]

However, MATLAB's 3D plot coordinate system is oriented with Z up which is inconsistent with the way the data is recorded - making visualization confusing. I understand that Matlab is also using a left handed coordinate system, except that it's rotated 90deg clockwise about the x-axis.

[image]

I've tried using the `camup` command which gets kind of close to what I want, but as soon as the plot is rotated in the GUI, the `camup` is thrown away and the plot reverts back to the above convention.

I would prefer not to rotate my data 90deg clockwise about the x-axis because it will introduce another level of ambiguity when it comes time for analysis and debugging.

EDIT: I think this sequence of instructions gets close.

[image]

```
set(gca, 'YDir', 'reverse');
camup([0 1 0]);
xlabel('X (mm)');
ylabel('Y (mm)');
zlabel('Z (mm)');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot a left handed coordinate system by reversing the direction of any one of the axes. This is controlled by the `XDir`, `YDir`, or `ZDir` properties of the `axes`.

```
surf(peaks)
set(gca, 'ZDir', 'reverse')
xlabel('x')
ylabel('y')
zlabel('z')
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think you might have misunderstood the question. The y-axis is supposed to be the "up" direction. I don't see any differences between your screenshot and the one I originally posted.

Comment: @Carpetfizz: the difference is that this plot has the z-axis pointing down, becoming a left-handed coordinate system. MATLAB’s default is right-handed. If you rotate these axes you’ll get the view you want.

Comment: oh, I see it now - thanks! but I guess I can't view the plot like the first image in the original post where the y-axis is the "up" vector?

Comment: @Carpetfizz: combine this with your `camup` command? I don’t know why it would be reset. Sounds like a bug? I’ll have to try that out.

Comment: Yeah as soon as I rotate the scene with my mouse the camera up gets reset

Comment: It also doesn't create the desired effect, even without rotating